# Фон с тенью в CSS

Tags: html, css

Коллеги, на сайте такой код:

```
<body>
 <DIV class="center">
  <DIV class="main">
```

Где:

```
.center {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.main {
width:867px;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
background-image:url(images/main_bckg_line.png); 
background-repeat:repeat-y; 
height:100%;
}
```

Имеем проблему: при прокрутке окошка скроллером или изменении размеров браузера фон "трётся".
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что проблема в относительных размерах: ширина 100%-ного полноэкранного режима не равна ширине 100% свернутого окна. А ширина дочернего окна задана явно. Конфликт. Попробуйте задать фиксированные везде размеры. Либо везде %.